# What is the verb for "to give someone admission to a place"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

What is the verb for "giving admission to someone" e.g. in a clinic? How can I say?

> An old man with thyroid mass was **given admission** to our clinic.

Can I say?

> An old man with thyroid mass was admissioned to our clinic.

However, I didn't find *admission* usage as verb. Is there a suitable verb for this usage?

Comment: Hmm... I wonder if there is web site that could help in such situation...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The verb is ***admit***, and the passive is *BE admitted*, so:

> An old man with a thyroid mass **was admitted** to our clinic.

This is the sort of thing that a good dictionary should provide as a matter of course. I am shocked to find that none of the four online dictionaries I consulted did so. The nearest any of them came was Merriam-Webster's first definition:

> 1. a :  the act or process of **admitting**
>      b :  the state or privilege of being **admitted**

Oxford offers this, under **Origin** after its definitions.

> Late Middle English: from Latin *admissio(n-)*, from the verb *admittere* (see **admit**).

I suppose they feel that giving you a broad hint is sufficient.

---

It may be helpful to know that most *-mission* words are similarly verbed: *commission < commit, emission < emit, permission < permit, remission < remit, transmission < transmit.*  However, there is no verb form in ordinary use for *intermission* or for bare *mission*.